# Relative layout is hiding the toolbar's title in Android

Tags: android, layout, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to place 3 images on the end of the toolbar of the navigation drawer activity like this.

[image: What I need actually]

[image: What I'm currently getting]

When using relative layout for aligning, I'm not able to see the "Home" title, I need to align three images to the right of the toolbar like this, and also I need to show the title. Where was I wrong, and how can I achieve it? The first image is what I'm expecting and second image is what I needed.

Here's what I've tried:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/homepage_toolbar_color"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/kit_icon"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_80sdp"/>


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/price_toolbar_icon"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/chat_toolbar_icon"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: you are covering your toolbar title from child relative layout

Comment: if you are using relative layout , like this , then you need to add a textview in this child relative layout , and set your title there.

Comment: @Thunder Yes done :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a TextVieW near the images with the title. It should show all this way. You place this in the relative layout before the first imageview:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/Txv_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Home" />
```

Comment: Could you provide some code example that displays how this could be done?

Comment: <TextView  android:id="@+id/Txv_home" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Home" />

Comment: you place this in the relative layout before the first imageview

Comment: I've added your comments into your answer.